# как загрузить изображения через тег img только на разрешениях 800px и выше

Tags: html, html5, img

Надо загрузить изображения через тег `img` только на разрешениях 800px и выше. Если разрешения экрана меньше 800px, картинка не должна загружаться.

Comment: Это лучше сделать через тег picture

Comment: добавлю только, что `picture` не поддерживается IE

Answer (score 0):

```html
<picture>
 <source srcset="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6Rh9.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)">
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg8E9.jpg" alt="ширина меньше 800 пикселей и IE">
</picture>
```